# Notations to represent a smoothed function/variable

Tags: notation, interpolation

I am writing an academic paper. In this paper, I already defined some discrete functions $f$, $g$ and variables $P$, $Q$. After that, some smoothed versions of them were derived. I was wondering what is the best notations to represent these smoothed functions & variables?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I choose to use $\tilde{f}$ to represent smoothed $f$, because in convex optimization $\tilde{f}$ is the [extended-value extension](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725/10725-S08/slides/convexfns2.pdf) which extends the domain of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$.